# Where to upload Firebase Node.js client?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nodemailer

I have build a `Node.js` simple client that monitors Firebase database changes and post emails using `Nodemailer`. It works great on my machine, Now I want to upload it to a server, But don't have any background. What is the most simple hosting service i can use? I don't expect high traffic at this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can recommend Heroku. They allow you to upload your code in many different way. They also have a nice page that list all the methods that they have, you can check it out hear: https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/deployment.

In addition to that, you can create an app for free, it will go to sleep, meaning it won't be up all the time, but it is a nice way to test and play with your deployment. Then it is just $7 a month to keep the lights on :)

There are many more hostings on-line, but I will argue that this one is the most straight forward with many resources for developers.

Comment: I have followed their tutorial deployed my app and the app seem not to work

Comment: Not it is time to talk with uncle Google and start asking questions :) because each question related to Heroku will be answered somewhere. But to make your life easier, check this article to get to the app logs https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging. Happy debugging :)

Comment: Don't forget to up vote my answer if you think that it did help you :)

Comment: Thanks! @David Gatti